# background color disappears when scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, background-color

when I scroll horizontal the page, the background color disappear. How to solve?
This is the code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0 auto;">
    <div align="center" width="100%" style=" background-color: #183337; height: 50px; ">
        <table align="center" width="100%" border="0">    
            <tr>        
                <td>            
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa        
                </td>    
            </tr>    
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[LOOK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3kdu6/)

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

To the styling for that div.

Here is how it will look. http://jsfiddle.net/3kdu6/4/